# Java2CRMCRUD: Required field 'MetadataId' is misssing

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, wsdl2java

I am accessing Microsoft online dynamics CRM service using the source code generated as described in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx using WSDL2Java
I get an exception on the following line of code
OrganizationServiceStub.ExecuteResponse response = serviceStub.execute(exe)

The exception is of type IOrganizationService_Execute_OrganizationServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage.
And the detailed message I get is 'Required field 'MetadataId' is misssing'.

Please help me with the 'MetadataId'. How to get this field. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: Is there some code we can look at?

Comment: What are you passing in the execute method. Ditto, code please.

Comment: Seems like a "Post-and-Forget"

Comment: Hi guys , sorry, couldn't check my own post.  I found the solution.
BTW, thanks for you time.